# how to store form data in table via controller

Tags: database, forms, magento, model-view-controller, model

I need to save form data in table . I need to know better way. Is it better to store from controller. i have tried using following code but no success

form

```
<form id="orderapproval-item-form" class="orderapproval-hidden" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('orderapproval/customercart/remarksdecline');?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="message" class="orderapproval-disabled" value="<?php echo $this->__('Enter decline reason'); ?>" id="decline" />
<input type="submit" value="<?php echo $this->__('Decline'); ?>" onclick="namet()" />
```

controller

```
    public function remarksdeclineAction()
    {
       $model =Mage::getModel('OrderApproval/sales_quote_item_order');
$model->setItemcomment($message);
$model->save(); // save data

    }
```

model/orderapproval.php

```
<?php
class ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model_OrderApproval extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
        public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('orderapproval/sales_quote_item_order');
    }
}
```

model/resource/orderapproval.php

```
<?php
class ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model_Resource_OrderApproval extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
        public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('orderapproval/sales_quote_item_order', 'item_id');
    }
}
```

model/resource/orderapproval/collection.php

```
<?php
class ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model_Resource_OrderApproval_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{
        protected function _constuct(){
 $this->_init('orderapproval/sales_quote_item_order'); 
 }
}
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <ZetaPrints_OrderApproval>
      <version>3</version>
    </ZetaPrints_OrderApproval>
  </modules>

  <global>
    <models>
      <orderapproval>
        <class>ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_resource</resourceModel>
      </orderapproval>

      <ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_resource>
         <class>ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model_Resource</class>
         <entities>
             <OrderApproval>
               <table>sales_quote_item_order</table>
             </OrderApproval>
          </entities>
    </ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_resource>

      <sales>
        <rewrite>
          <quote>ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model_Quote</quote>
        </rewrite>
      </sales>
    </models>

    <blocks>
      <orderapproval>
        <class>ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Block</class>
      </orderapproval>
    </blocks>

    <helpers>
      <orderapproval>
        <class>ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Helper</class>
      </orderapproval>
    </helpers>

    <resources>
      <orderapproval_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>ZetaPrints_OrderApproval</module>
          <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>Core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </orderapproval_setup>

      <orderapproval_write>
        <connection><use>Core_write</use></connection>
      </orderapproval_write>

      <orderapproval_read>
        <connection><use>Core_read</use></connection>
      </orderapproval_read>
    </resources>
```

its my folder name and file name of model folder

```
ZetaPrints/OrderApproval/Model/orderapproval.php



ZetaPrints/OrderApproval/Model/Resource/orderapproval.php
ZetaPrints/OrderApproval/Model/Resource/orderapproval/connection.php
```

Comment: i am getting error .....Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setItemcomment() on boolean

Comment: sorry i did not get

Comment: your controller is calling?

Comment: yes my controller ia calling

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: i am getting error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setItemcomment() on boolean

Comment: it doesnt get the object thats why giving error

Comment: than what should i do

Comment: use $model =Mage::getModel('orderapproval/sales_quote_item_order');

Comment: same error on same line

Comment: check your name conversions somewhere use capital A and somewhere small

Comment: i have checked and changed too but still i am getting error

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code in controller.

```
$variable = $this->getRequest()->getParam('form_element');
```

Final code will be something similar to this.

```
public function remarksdeclineAction()
{
$variable = $this->getRequest()->getParam('form_element');
$model = Mage::getModel('orderapproval/orderapproval');
$model->setItemcomment($variable);
$model->save(); // save data
}
```

Also please double check the namespace again in config.xml

Comment: my module name is zetaprints_orderapproval

Comment: what should i write here namespace or module name

Comment: i am getting this error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function beginTransaction() on boolean

Comment: app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php on line 313

Comment: my model file is correct <?php
class ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model_OrderApproval extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
        public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('orderapproval/sales_quote_item_order');
    }
}

Comment: orderapproval is module name and sales_quote_item_order is tab le name

Comment: @ErSarveshVTiwari change 

`$this->_init('orderapproval/sales_quote_item_order', 'item_id');`

to 

`$this->_init('orderapproval/orderapproval', 'item_id');`

in all places. `model, resource model and resource collection`

try and let me know.

Comment: i have changed but still getting same error my table name is sales_quote_item_order and field name is itemcomment

Comment: i have changed my config.xml too